# Excel VBA Conditional Formatting Error

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I am using the following code to format the `Cell.Interior.Color` and `Cell.Font.Color` of certain cells which fullfill a in `Tabelle4.Cells("B2")` pre-definied criteria:

```
Sub ColorTest1()

Dim lastcell As Long
Dim Cellclr As Long
Dim Fontclr As Long

lastcell = Tabelle3.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row
Cellclr = RGB(232, 245, 246)
Fontclr = RGB(26, 155, 167)


    For Each Cell In Tabelle3.Range(Tabelle3.Cells(9, 3), Tabelle3.Cells(lastcell, 3))

        If Cell <> "" And Cell.Value <= Tabelle4.Cells("B2") Then

            Cell.Interior.Color = Cellclr
            Cell.Font.Color = Fontclr

        End If

    Next Cell

End Sub
```

However my condition line is not working out, but no error shown:

```
If Cell <> "" And Cell.Value <= Tabelle4.Cells("B2") Then
```

Does someone know whats going on here and probably how to fix it?

Comment: try to change Tabelle4.Cells("B2") to Tabelle4.Range("B2").Value
Also change Interior.color with Interior.CoroIndex

Comment: @Ionut With `Tabelle4.Range("B2").Value` the code works smooth.  Thanks alot :) Though, I did not apply `ColorIndex`

Comment: @Ionut - `ColorIndex` should give an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the code would look like, if you simplify it as much as possible:

```
Sub ColorTest()

    Dim cellClr     As Long
    Dim fontClr     As Long
    Dim cell        As Range

    cellClr = RGB(232, 245, 246)
    fontClr = RGB(26, 155, 167)

    For Each cell In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 5))
        If cell <> "" And cell.Value <= 5 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = cellClr
            cell.Font.Color = fontClr
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Now, if you enter something in the Range `A1:E5` of the `ActiveSheet`, it will become green with green background.

Comment: That's right but wouldn't have solved my problem with the condition :)

Comment: @HPM - true, but it is a good idea to start from something small and working and then build further.